# Update local password to match domain password?

Tags: network, password, active-directory

Scenario: company-provided MacBook Pro, Big Sur 11.2.3, and I used it in office for a few months on the wired LAN and Wireless networks.  COVID therefore WFH, but now my login password while home does not get updated when I update my domain password.

I always change my password from one of the servers in the company datacenter, not from the MacBook. Next time log into Mac, only the old password still works.

When I come into the office and connect MacBook to the wired LAN, I can log in initially with the domain credential.  But as soon as I disconnect from the network and restart/relog, only my year-old domain credential works.  The current password no longer works.

How does one update the credential stored in MacOS with the current domain values?  Also is there a setting that will allow it to keep updated even though remote via VPN?